# iOS8: Type is wrong when using getValue to unwrap NSNumber

Tags: nsnumber, ios8

I have discovered, that, unlike the previous versions, using the following code:

```
NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0;
[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
```

makes a mistake: The NSNumber Value is unwrapped as float, but it gets interpreted later as double (because NSTimeInterval is a double). Of course, on a bit-level, those types don´t fit, and thus the values are wrong (x*E^(-315)).

In prior versions, that code did the perfectly right thing: Unwrapping the value as double!

This code will work, but is not an optimal solution:

```
float animationDuration = 0;
[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
```

Did anybody discover the same? And how would you solve that (it is strange, that getValue changes the type that it unwraps suddenly, isn´t it?)

*I have to admit that I didn´t test it outside of the simulator. It´s on iOS8 simulator with xCode6 and OSX Mavericks.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` key provides a `NSNumber` object: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html.

   > UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey The key for an NSNumber object
   >   containing a double that identifies the duration of the animation in
   >   seconds. Available in iOS 3.0 and later. Declared in UIWindow.h.
2. The `getValue:` method is defined in `NSValue` class which is a superclass of `NSNumber` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/getValue:

The `NSValue` class is designed to keep an arbitrary-length memory state. And the `getValue:` method is intended to copy the *original* memory state to create the `NSValue` object. Anyway, accessing to the original state is usually meaningless in `NSNumber` class because it is designed as a *duck type*, and you should use `-[NSNumber doubleValue]` instead of accessing original memory state.

Anyway, by the definition of the `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` key, the `NSNumber` object must contain a double value, and this seems to be a bug. I think you can claim a bug in Apple radar.

Comment: Sorry for not marking your answer as correct before the bounty expired (did not look for the post this week yet)